# Button display does not increment PHP,Script

Tags: php

I'm a beginner, trying out on php and script.
the following code is what I've tried.

```
 <?php
       for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
            echo "<button onclick = 'testBTN()'> TEST </button>";
            echo "<script> function testBTN(){ document.write ($i);}

</script>";
}
    ?>
```

Was wondering why when I click on the button, the number is always fixed at 49, it does not increment, from 0 to 49 for every button I clicked.

May I know why and how can I handle it.

Comment: you dont have a closing bracket

Comment: there is a closing bracket

Comment: Do  you try with $( document ).ready(function() {} in <script></script>

Comment: document.write (<?php echo $i; ?>); try this @moon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass your value in function parameter like this

```
<?php
      for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
           echo "<button onclick = 'testBTN(".$i.")'> TEST </button>";               
       }
       echo "<script> function testBTN(i){ document.write (i);}</script>";
?>
```

Comment: pass $i variable value as parameter  in `testBTN` function and print same value in script . do not assign $i variable value in both lines.Are you getting point?

Comment: glad to help you.   :)

Comment: no. Why angry ?? everyone has own skill to solve problems. and your knowledge is good too...@Exprator

Comment: sorry , can I ask you if I would like to add it behind a link, how can I do so? forexample, add variable i behind www.google.com

Comment: what you really want to do?@moon

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
       echo "<button onclick = 'testBTN(".$i.")'> TEST </button>";
    }
       echo "<script> 
             function testBTN(i){ 
                      document.write(i++);
                       }
              </script>";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the for loop.You are printing 50 buttons with 50 definition of testBTN function.
just

```html
          
         echo "<button onclick = 'testBTN()'> TEST </button>";
                    echo "<script> 
    var i=0;               
    function testBTN(){ document.write (i);i++;}
        
        </script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Moon.

Your problem is in function.
All functions and variable you define in javascript global inherited from window global.

For example, you define `var myvar = 1;` not in function.
You can access this variable something like this

```js
var MyVar = 123;

alert("Without window: " + MyVar);
alert("With window" + window.MyVar)
```

function in JS is same as a variable. You define `function myFunc() = { alert("hello") }`
Example:

```js
function myFunc() { alert("Hello func"); }

myFunc();
window.myFunc();
```

And a little bit about your case.
Your PHP generated code something like:

```html
<button onclick = 'testBTN()'> TEST </button>
<script> function testBTN(){ document.write (1);} </script>
<button onclick = 'testBTN()'> TEST </button>
<script> function testBTN(){ document.write (2);} </script> 
// ....
```

But browser JS see your code like:

```js
function testBTN(){ document.write (1);}
function testBTN(){ document.write (2);}
```

You rewrite your prev function.
Example:

```js
function myFunc() { alert("Hello me"); }
function myFunc() { alert("Hello me 2"); }
function myFunc() { alert("Hello me 3"); }
function myFunc() { alert("Hello me 4"); }
function myFunc() { alert("Hello me 5"); }

myFunc();
```

For this case, you have 2 solutions
1:

```
<?php
  for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
       echo "<button onclick = 'testBTN". $i ."()'> TEST ". $i ." </button>";
       echo "<script> function testBTN".$i."(){ document.write (".$i.");}</script>";
   }
?>
```

```html
<button onclick = 'testBTN1()'> TEST 1 </button>
<script> function testBTN1(){ document.write (1);}</script>
<button onclick = 'testBTN2()'> TEST 2 </button>
<script> function testBTN2(){ document.write (2);}</script>
....
```

2:

```
<?php
  echo "<script> function testBTN(".$i."){ document.write (".$i.");}</script>";
  for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
       echo "<button onclick = 'testBTN(". $i .")'> TEST ". $i ." </button>";
  }
?>
```

```html
<script> function testBTN(i){ document.write (i);}</script>

<button onclick = 'testBTN(1)'> TEST 1 </button>
<button onclick = 'testBTN(2)'> TEST 2 </button>
....
```

Second example is better becouse you create only 1 function, not 49.